# ReactJS Hooks Update an Array with another Array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

i want to Update an empty array by another array,
i cant realy figure out how todo that,

```
const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState([]);
```

and i want to update the empty array with another array like this:

```
PlayerService.getAvatars()
                    .then(response => {
                        setAvatar(avatar => [...avatar, response])
                    })
```

the problem here is, that the 4 items i get from the response , 
they will be set to the first element of the avatar array, not to multiple,

that means, i get under avatar[0] , all the items together, they dont split up like they should.

i hope you can follow me, im not a native english speaker

Comment: try `setAvatar(response)` if response is an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can concat array if you want to combine two array like this .

```
PlayerService.getAvatars()
    .then(response => {
        let arr1 = avtar;
        let arr2 = response;
        let arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);
        setAvatar(arr3)
    })
```

Comment: thats very weird, in arr3 are all elements, but if i do setAvatar and then console.log it , it is still empty then .. o.O

Comment: this is the async operation . console it before return and check again .

Comment: Ahh perfect, i didnt know that it is async ... , so at the end i can do setAvatar(response) , but thanks for all the Info, it helpt me to fix my problem